# How to check if a post belongs to a category that has only 1 posts?

Tags: categories

Although I've done some searches on Google, I have not found an answer to this question:
Is there a way to check if a post belongs to a category that has only 1 posts (is the only one in its category)? I need to perform this check on `single.php`.

```
if ( 'the_magic_check' ) {
 // do something
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) to get the categories belonging to the post. You can then use `$category->count` to return the amount of posts for specific category attached to the post

Example:

If a post has just one category attached to it, you can do the following

```
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->count;
```

In your check to see if there is only one post in the specific category and then do something, you can try

```
if( 1 == $category[0]->count ) {
   // Do something if the category has one post only
}
```

Comment: Brilliant and simple!

Comment: Glad this post was useful to you. Enjoy :-)